# structure data to use to get ordered tags in the initial order

Tags: python

I have an xml file(input) that contains tags in some order : what I want to do is open the file that contains the tags,get them, do some operations on those tags in the order of their appearance and generate a new xml file which contains the same informations of the input file and the results I obtained by the processing performed on each tag in the same order they appear in the input file

To create the xml output file I used a dictionary as `{ tag: information after treatment ; tag : information after treatement }` I pass the result(the dictionary) to a function that allows me to generate the xml output file

so my problem is that the dictionary does not keep the tags in their original order(in the output file) I thought about creating a class for each tag that contains the tag and its information after treatment but I do not know if I'll get the same problem with a list of class(if at the end I'll get the tags in the bad order )  and if this is the case if you have a proposal on the way to get what i want (the data structure to use?)

In summary , will replacing the dictionary with a list of classes guarantee keeping the original order of appearance of tags in my output xml file ?

Thanks

Comment: could you not just use a specialist library like lxml or beautiful soup to store and modify the xml?

Comment: Presumably the tags are all distinct, and you just need to preserve their order.  So couldn't you create a list of the tags, in the order they appear, as a separate data structure, just so you can recover the order?  Maybe even add this as an extra item to your dictionary (if you want to keep everything together)?

Comment: Are you reading and writing the XML using any XML library currently? Why don't you just write your XML output as you consume each new tag?

Comment: I'm using minidom to handle xml Files

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for the answer I know I can add the order of tags to the dictionary but I wanted to do that in an "elegant" way .. so there is no data structure that allows me to keep the initial order of tags?

Comment: @user3328690 dictionaries are unordered in Python. If you need a dictionary-like data structure that retains order, there's [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). However, in your case the right thing to do is to use an XML parser like [`lxml`](http://www.lxml.de) to read and write the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an `OrderedDict` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).